# Hibernate Search - issue indexing embedded / associated objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I'm having difficulty adding index fields to embedded objects using hibernate search.

I have a simple example whereby a Company can have many CompanyAddress(es) - example of my setup is shown below:

Company.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="COMPANY")
@Indexed
public class Company implements Serializable {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
               cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth=1, includePaths={"postalCode"})
    private Set<CompanyAddress> address;

    ...

}
```

CompanyAddress.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="COMPANY_ADDRESS")
@Indexed
public class CompanyAddress implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    @ContainedIn
    private Company company;

    @Column(name="POSTAL_CODE", length=10)
    private String postalCode;

}
```

When I try to index I get the following error:

`Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000216: Found invalid @IndexedEmbedded->paths elements configured for member 'address' of class 'com.example.model.Company'. The invalid paths are [address.postalCode]`

Now if I swap the @Contained and @IndexedEmbedded to be on the address object I can index and find companies from addresses however I would wish to be able to include address fields in the Company index.

I'm using hibernate search 5.11.11.Final.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved this - adding an @Field annotation to the postalCode attribute meant the field was indexed and the error didn't occur.

Hopefully this will be useful for anyone else with similar problems.

Comment: Sounds good, be sure to mark your answer as Accepted once you are able to.